# Definition: sum $f+g $ with $ f,g \in Hom_K(E,F) $

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need the definition of sum $ f+g $ with $ f,g \in Hom_K(E,F) $...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $f,g$ are linear maps from $E$ to $F$, so we define $f+g$ to be the linear map that takes any vector $v\in E$ to $f(v) + g(v)$.

Comment: but $ + $ in $ f(v) + g(v)$ is usual addition?

Comment: Yeah it's just the normal addition of vectors in $F$.

Comment: Therefore $+$ is the binary operation defined on $F$ with $(F;+)$ is abelian group..??

Comment: Yeah just standard addition of vectors $f(v)$ and $g(v)$ from $F$.

Comment: ok thank you soo much.....

Comment: @Garnak: Actually if $E$ is an arbitrary set and $F$ is a group, then the set of maps $E \to F$ becomes a group via the pointwise operations. If $F$ is abelian and $E$ is a group, the homomorphisms $E \to F$ form a subgroup.

Comment: It was tagged linear algebra :)

Comment: in this case $ E $ and $F$ are vector spaces on $K$...

Comment: Linearity is irrelevant, it's just addition of functions. The only requirement is that the codomain be a group under $+$.

Comment: Nevertheless the point of the definition was to be understandable and relevant to the question, which was about linear maps between vector spaces.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that $ E, F $ are vector spaces on $K$... :)